# Fatal error: Uncaught ReflectionException: Class IlluminateContractsHttpKernel does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

> Fatal error: Uncaught ReflectionException: Class IlluminateContractsHttpKernel does not exist in C:\xampp\htdocs\erc_new\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:788 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\erc_new\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(788): ReflectionClass->__construct('IlluminateContr...') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\erc_new\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(667): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('IlluminateContr...') #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\erc_new\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(615): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve('IlluminateContr...', Array) #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\erc_new\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(767): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('IlluminateContr...', Array) #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\erc_new\public\index.php(52): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('IlluminateContr...') #5 C:\xampp\htdocs\erc_new\server.php(21): require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #6 {mai in C:\xampp\htdocs\erc_new\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php on line 788

auto it is showin the Kernel error. thought i have not made any changes.
i have already tried checking the Kernel.php files.
more over i have already deleated the vendor and composer.lock file and install the composer .
But also getting the the above error.

Moreover I also  have deleted the every things that recedes on bootstrap/cache/

Comment: you can run on the root directory ```composer update``` then ```composer dump-autoload```

Comment: thank your for the response @SaimunHossain but still gives me the same error as above!

Comment: what are you doing that causes this error?

Comment: i have no idea.. file was on server .. and got this issue, it also doesnot work in local too..